# Access Docker Container Name By DNS Subdomain

Tags: docker, dns, containers

Basically, I have Docker Swarm running on physical machine with public IPv4 address and registered domain, say **example.com**

Now, I would like to access the running containers from Internet using their names as a subdomain. 
For instance, lets say there is a **mysql** container running with name **mysqldb**. I would like to be able to access it from Internet by the following DNS:

**mysqldb.example.com**

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a so-called solution.
In general it's not possible :)

However, some known ports can be forwarded to a container by using HTTP reverse-proxies such as Nginx, haproxy etc.